# Ошибка при проверке времени в базе данных

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Ошибка:

`    if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - last_command_use_time).hour > 1:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'`

Код:

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = conn.cursor()


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    last_command_use_time = \
    cur.execute('SELECT get_card_cd FROM users WHERE user_id={}'.format(message.chat.id)).fetchone()[0]

    user_id = message.chat.id

    if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - last_command_use_time).hour > 1:
        # Если кнопка не нажималась или с прошлого запуска команды прошёл час
        cur.execute('UPDATE users SET get_card_cd =? WHERE user_id =?', (datetime.datetime.now(), user_id))
        conn.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нужное сообщение...')
    else:
        # Если же час ещё не прошёл
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Подождите!')


bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Что такое get_card_cd?

Comment: название столбца в бд

Comment: Можешь показать `print(type(last_command_use_time), last_command_use_time)` после запроса.

Comment: @panickx какого именно столбца?

Comment: Возможно этот пост будет вам полезен
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360461/difference-in-timestamp-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дата из базы данных выводится в формате 'str'. Это связано с тем что SQLite не поддерживает встроенное хранилище DateTime класса, но SQLite позволяет нам работать с типами временных меток. Мы можем хранить и извлекать информацию о date и datetime Python, хранящуюся в таблицах базы данных SQLite, преобразуя их в типы date и datetime Python, и наоборот.

Попробуйте дописать

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES, check_same_thread=False)
```

```py
sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
```

Эта константа используется как значение параметра detect_types метода connect().
Если использовать этот параметр в методе connect(), то модуль sqlite3 будет парсить тип каждой получаемой колонки.

```py
sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES
```

После парсинга используется словарь конвертации типов для поиска выполнения конкретной функции конвертации.